# Magento getData from guest on success.phtml

Tags: php, magento, subtotal

I am trying to get the subtotal amount on checkout success page. It works good for registred users:

```
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$amount = $_order->getData('subtotal');
$total  = number_format($amount, 2);
```

But when the order is processed by a guest, `$total` is empty.

What can be done?

**P.S.:** I am using *Magento 1.6.1 CE*

Comment: Are you sure the $amount is not empty? ;)

Comment: ;-) amount and of course total are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from Magento's `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php`:

```
if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
    return $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
} else {
    return Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address');
}
```

I am 99% sure you can do exactly the same with `getOrder()` and with `Mage_Checkout_Block_Success` =)

**Note:** the `isCustomerLoggedIn()` method is defined at `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract` which is not inherited by `Mage_Checkout_Block_Success`. So, you could simply use its implementation:

```
public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
}
```

E.g. your code now shall look like this:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getOrder();
} else {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
}
```

Sorry for saying non-sense things before...

Comment: hi shybobycha! tried your code. thank you very much. but it outputs the same things. registered users see price, non registered not! :/

Comment: damn it, i pasted the code to the wrong position. within an if statement which checks for logged in status. and then - of course - it wont display for guest users. so i pasted my code now to the right place. with your code, the page parsing breaks. i dunno why?!

Comment: First of all, be sure to paste the last code in my answer. Then, be ready to rename `$order` to `$_order` if you did not change other of your code. At last, please, be so nice and show me the log within `var/log/exception.log`, `var/log/system.log` and Apache log (tail lines) where the Magento writes its exceptions.

Comment: oh, right. where did you pasted that code - within the Block or template it would be nice. but not within Model or Controller...